# selected directory is not a valid glassfish home

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm studying JAVA, using intelliJ IDEA as IDE , I want to set Glassfish as server on it. Working on linux, glassfish already installed on it (working from command line).

When i create new JavaEE project on intelliJ, on "Application Server" line i choose new -> "glassfish server" and then select glassfish5 folder but IntelliJ just doesn't accept it with error code : "selected directory is not a valid glassfish home".

I'm selecting the glassfish5 home directory, not the one named glassfish in it (tried it , didn't work either).
I've tried to change glassfish version, tried to unzip glassfish to another directory ...
Still exactly same error.
No problem installing tomcat on intelliJ, but no more clue installing glassfish.

Thanks anyone trying to help

Answer (score 2):

I've found my mistake : i've forgotten to give local user permissions to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1, Glassfish 5 works without issues. Double check you have these directories/files in the installation directory. Try a clean server installation if it doesn't work.

[image: gf]

[image: gf2]

If nothing helps, provide the link to the Glassfish distribution that doesn't work for you and specify IntelliJ IDEA version.